# Have two full width HTML elements overlap but both be interactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I have a design that requires sections to be full width of the page, but the content is within a container (`article`). With that in mind, there is a need for an aside that floats above the full-with sections that needs to be interactive (`aside`).

Both `article` and `side` have content that needs to be interacted with. The issue then is one has to have a priority over the other and at the moment, I've settled for the `article`, but it's not ideal.

https://jsfiddle.net/WolfieZero/aouu1v40/3/

Any ideas? I wanted to see if it could be fixed with CSS first but thinking this might be a job for JS (jQuery in this case).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to switch the z-indexes, now the links in both areas will be clickable.

```
.module {
    z-index: 2;
}
section > div {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Before, you were prioritising the "section", so that even though the "module" *appeared* to be on top (due to its positioning properties), its z-index meant it wasn't actually accessible.

See https://jsfiddle.net/aouu1v40/6/ for a demo

Comment: No idea why I didn't try that originally and but it works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Actually, testing this a bit more, it doesn't work. It will work whilst the aside is `position: absolute;` but when it changes to `position: fixed;` the issue reverts back :(

Comment: With all due respect, it works with the code you gave in the question, I can't second-guess any changes you decide to make in future. If you've got an issue with a different version of the code, you really need to ask a new question about it, since it's a different scenario. This answer should be accepted as working based on the original information given, thanks :-).

Comment: So based on the solution you've provided (https://jsfiddle.net/aouu1v40/6/) it works in the initial state where position is absolute. If you scroll down the page to a point where the text on the left aligns with the link in the pink module, it's still broken where the position is fixed. I'm testing on Chrome v66 and Firefox v60 with no changes to the code.

Comment: So there are two solutions. One with JS using `position: absolute;` the whole way (https://jsfiddle.net/WolfieZero/aouu1v40/11/). Another with pure CSS using `position: sticky;` provided by another person (https://jsfiddle.net/aouu1v40/10/)

Comment: Ok sorry I hadn't appreciated that. Is there any particular reason it has to stop scrolling and disappear when it gets to a certain point on the page? I'm just thinking you could set `aside` as `position:fixed` and then get rid of all your jQuery code, i.e. like this https://jsfiddle.net/aouu1v40/12/

Comment: Actually even if we keep all the jQuery code, we can just change `.module {
    z-index: 2;
}` to `aside {
    z-index: 2;
}` and it seems to work ok: https://jsfiddle.net/aouu1v40/13/

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. The issue is with the left sided links not being clickable now.

Comment: True, how about https://jsfiddle.net/aouu1v40/14/ - simplified the CSS a bit. Your structure is quite complex considering what you're actually drawing.